# How to debug this metamsk error ? - Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload:

Tags: truffle, metamask, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ganache

I have a DApp integrated with metamask and ganache, front-end built on react. I am getting this error when I interact with the smart contract from front-end, contract send calls. Smart contract compiles fine and all the test passes.

So, to check the validity of Metamask connection, I tried the truffle petshop DApp; the same error still persists. I tried resetting account, re-installing metamask, creating new accounts - still facing the same error.

Following are the versions

metamask version: 7.7.9 
web3.js version:1.2.7
Node JS version: v10.15.3
truffle version: 5.1.34
os: macOS 10.15.4
browser: Google Chrome 83.0.4103.113

```
MetaMask - RPC Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":6876026167411,"jsonrpc":"2.0","params":["0xf873048504a817c80083014cdc94ede8c1a58f1210c2075faa916cea1fed41cf24228829a2241af62c000084d0febe4c822d45a086ac8d46d13dc5f2f6d0b168e3a24bc140015f6bc6164ef330f145c68566fe61a042b9f3da876f8625fa3c35df4b5b0b96db9659b477162f5f29313d2d6879fddb"],"method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object] {code: -32603, message: "Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {"id":68…method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]", stack: "Error: Error: [ethjs-rpc] rpc error with payload {…method":"eth_sendRawTransaction"} [object Object]"}
```

To recreate the issue please follow steps below

find the codebase here: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e-5APvS5otuT5Lf3s8X_LXR1vSInfBa0/view?usp=sharing)

after unzipping: 
install dependencies: `npm install` 
compile contracts: `truffle compile` 
migarte contracts: `truffle migrate` 
run the front end browser: `npm run dev` 
access the dapp from browser at localhost:3000

Comment: Did you restart ganache? A common cause of this problem is when ganache has been restarted, so cached nonce by Metamask doesn't match the nonce in the network. Try resetting the account state in Metamask menu.

Comment: appreciate the suggestion. I was using an older version of Ganache, I updated to the new recent release and the DApp works fine. Thanks